# Column outer joined in subquery (ORA-01799)

Tags: oracle, subquery, left-join

Oracle 11g R2:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 
   (REC_ID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
    REV_ID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE
   );
   
INSERT ALL
INTO TABLE_1 (REC_ID,REV_ID) 
VALUES (1,23)
INTO TABLE_1 (REC_ID,REV_ID) 
VALUES (1,36)
INTO TABLE_1 (REC_ID,REV_ID) 
VALUES (1,52)
INTO TABLE_1 (REC_ID,REV_ID) 
VALUES (2,19)
INTO TABLE_1 (REC_ID,REV_ID) 
VALUES (2,67)
INTO TABLE_1 (REC_ID,REV_ID) 
VALUES (2,98)
SELECT * FROM dual;

CREATE TABLE TABLE_2
   (REC_ID NUMBER(20,0) NOT NULL ENABLE
   ); 
     
INSERT ALL
INTO TABLE_2 (REC_ID) 
VALUES (1)
INTO TABLE_2 (REC_ID) 
VALUES (2)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

I want to join Table 2 with Table 1 but only where Table 1 REV_ID is the minimum REV_ID for a certain REC_ID.

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| REC_ID | REC_ID | REV_ID |
+--------+--------+--------+
|      1 |      1 |     23 |
|      2 |      2 |     19 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

This Select:

```
SELECT * from TABLE_2 T2
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_1 T1 on T1.REC_ID = T2.REC_ID 
and T1.REV_ID = (SELECT MIN(REV_ID) from T1 where T1.REC_ID = T2.REC_ID)
```

works on MSSQL Server 2017 but raises the error:

`ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery` in oracle.

SQL Fiddle: [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/25d14/3)

Question:
How can I rewrite the query so that the join works in all oracle versions?

Comment: What is the question? You should upgrade to 12c where this limit is lifted.

Comment: Move the sub query to the where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use CTE with `row_number` to *classify* the  row with the minimal `REV_ID` and the outer join only to those rows.

The advantage is this approach works even if you want some other attributes from `T1`

```
with t1_min as
(select REC_ID, REV_ID,
row_number() over (partition by REC_ID order by  REV_ID) as rn
from TABLE_1)
SELECT t2.rec_id t2_rec_id,t1.rec_id t1_rec_id,
t1.rev_id
from TABLE_2 T2
LEFT OUTER JOIN t1_min T1 on T1.REC_ID = T2.REC_ID 
and t1.rn = 1

 T2_REC_ID  T1_REC_ID     REV_ID
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1         23
         2          2         19
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query -

```
SELECT *
from TABLE_2 T2
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT REC_ID, MIN(REV_ID)
                   FROM TABLE_1
                  GROUP BY REC_ID) T1 on T1.REC_ID = T2.REC_ID;
```

[Link.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/25d14/9)